# Node.js application running out of stack memory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a bot to connect to my node.js server and I am getting some strange crashes that all produce this error message: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` Whats even stranger, is that this doesn't seam to be triggered by any specific command at all, since this code alone:

```
function loop() {
  loop();
}

loop();
```

produces the crash. I have looked at my memory usage and it is nowhere near the limit. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Look up "call stack". Sorry, got to run, but it's an important concept in programming.

Answer (score 2):

Calling a function itself allocates some space on the system stack, and returning from that function frees that space*. If the function calls itself again and again without returning, it's going to, sooner or later, run out of stack memory.
If you want an infinite loop that doesn't run out of memory, you can write something like `while (true);`.

*In high-level languages, it does so automatically. In assembly language, not exactly, you need to do that manually, you need to do stuff like this (this is from `permutations.aec` file from [this](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/ArithmeticExpressionCompiler/blob/master/ArithmeticExpressionCompiler.zip?raw=true) ZIP):

```
                fld dword [subscript]
                fistp dword [subscript]
                mov ebx,[subscript]
                pushIntegerToTheSystemStack (countDigits+ebx)
                pushStringToTheSystemStack integerSign
                call [printf]
                add esp,8 ;Cleaning up the system stack after "printf".
```

As I approached assembly knowing only high-level languages (such as JavaScript), that behaviour was confusing to me at first and caused my app to crash on large inputs before I figured out what's going on.

Comment: And what can I do about it?

Comment: Well thats a quite long answer for a while true loop

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @user11914177 Well, I need to explain that to in a way he would understand. falkus7, do you understand why that works and what you tried doesn't? Is what I've written somehow too long?

Comment: @FlatAssembler well the first paragraph would have been enough

Comment: @user11914177 It might mislead him into thinking all programming languages are like that. Assembly is profoundly different in that regard.